# Joule Thomson Coefficient derivation

Tags: thermodynamics

In deriving Joule Thomson effect coefficient, why do we take $dH=0$ and also why do we take $H$ as a function of $T$ and $P$ only and not $V$?
i.e. why do we take 
$$(\partial H/ \partial T)dT+(\partial H/\partial P)dP=0$$
and not

$$(\partial H/\partial T)dT+(\partial H/\partial P)dP+(\partial H/\partial V)dV=0$$

Any links would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$\Delta H = 0$ follows from the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics, which accounts for material entering and leaving a system.

The equation of state for a single phase material of constant composition is of the form f(T,P,V)=0.  So, once any two of these are specified at an equilibrium state, the third is known.  It takes only two intensive properties to specify the equilibrium state of a single phase material of constant composition.

Answer (score 2):

First the throttling process. We take enthalpy to be constant partially because we are only concerned with local conditions.

Pretend the fluid is being pushed through by a piston, exerting pressure $P_i$ , while to enable the fluid to pass through, a second piston, with pressure  $P_f$, moves backwards.

$V_i$ is initial volume and $V_f$ is final volume.

There is taken to be no heat flow, so energy change is

$$U_f -U_i = Q + W = 0 + W_{left} + W_{right} $$

$W_{left}$ is taken to be positive and $W_{right}$ as  negative, so the change in energy is $$U_f- Ui=P_iV_i - P_fV_f$$

Rearranging this gives you

$$U_f + P_fV_f = U_i + P_iV_i$$ or
$H_f = H_i$ so enthalpy is constant during the throttling process, so $\partial H= 0$

From [Joule Thompson Coefficient Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect#Derivation_of_the_Joule.E2.80.93Thomson_coefficient)

> It is difficult to think physically about what the Joule–Thomson coefficient, ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$, represents. Also, modern determinations of ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$ do not use the original method used by Joule and Thomson, but instead measure a different, closely related quantity. Thus, it is useful to derive relationships between ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$ and other, more convenient quantities. That is the purpose of this section.
>
> The first step in obtaining these results is to note that the Joule–Thomson coefficient involves the three variables T, P, and H. A useful result is immediately obtained by applying the cyclic rule; in terms of these three variables that rule may be written

$${\displaystyle \left({\frac {\partial T}{\partial P}}\right)_{H}\left({\frac {\partial H}{\partial T}}\right)_{P}\left({\frac {\partial P}{\partial H}}\right)_{T}=-1.}$$

> Each of the three partial derivatives in this expression has a specific meaning. The first is ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$, the second is the constant pressure heat capacity, ${\displaystyle C_{\mathrm {p} }}$, defined by

$${\displaystyle C_{\mathrm {p} }=\left({\frac {\partial H}{\partial T}}\right)_{P}}$$

> and the third is the inverse of the isothermal Joule–Thomson coefficient, ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {T} }}$, defined by

$${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {T} }=\left({\frac {\partial H}{\partial P}}\right)_{T}}$$

> This last quantity is more easily measured than ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$. Thus, the expression from the cyclic rule becomes
>
> $${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }=-{\frac {\mu _{\mathrm {T} }}{C_{p}}}}$$

Wikipedia then develops the meaning of the above using $V $ below, so depending  on the age of the text you are using, it might make more sense to read this section below first.

> This equation can be used to obtain Joule-Thomson coefficients from the more easily measured isothermal Joule–Thomson coefficient. It is used in the following to obtain a mathematical expression for the Joule-Thomson coefficient in terms of the volumetric properties of a fluid.
>
> To proceed further, the starting point is the fundamental equation of thermodynamics in terms of enthalpy; this is

$${\displaystyle \mathrm {d} H=T\mathrm {d} S+V\mathrm {d} P.}$$

> Now "dividing through" by dP, while holding temperature constant, yields

$${\displaystyle \left({\frac {\partial H}{\partial P}}\right)_{T}=T\left({\frac {\partial S}{\partial P}}\right)_{T}+V}$$

> The partial derivative on the left is the isothermal Joule-Thomson coefficient, ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {T} }}$, and the one on the right can be expressed in terms of the coefficient of thermal expansion via a Maxwell relation. The appropriate relation is

$${\displaystyle \left({\frac {\partial S}{\partial P}}\right)_{T}=-\left({\frac {\partial V}{\partial T}}\right)_{P}=-V\alpha \,}$$

> where $α$ is the cubic coefficient of thermal expansion.

Replacing these two partial derivatives yields

$${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {T} }=-TV\alpha \ +V}$$

> This expression can now replace ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {T} }}$ in the earlier equation for ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$ to obtain

$${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }\equiv \left({\frac {\partial T}{\partial P}}\right)_{H}={\frac {V}{C_{\mathrm {p} }}}\left(\alpha T-1\right)\,}$$

> This provides an expression for the Joule–Thomson coefficient in terms of the commonly available properties heat capacity, molar volume, and thermal expansion coefficient. It shows that the Joule–Thomson inversion temperature, at which ${\displaystyle \mu _{\mathrm {JT} }}$ is zero, occurs when the coefficient of thermal expansion is equal to the inverse of the temperature. Since this is true at all temperatures for ideal gases, the Joule–Thomson coefficient of an ideal gas is zero at all temperatures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what is the explanation to start with

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what is the explanation to start with         dH=TdS+VdP.

Comment: Enthalpy (Symbol: H) is a measurement of energy in a thermodynamic system. It is the thermodynamic quantity equivalent to the total heat content of a system. It is equal to the internal energy of the system plus the product of pressure and volume.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy    Basically, for example  you would spend a lot of time calculating compression or expansion the long way, part by part of a cycle,  without this equation.