# Why is Joule Thomson Experiment Isoenthalpic?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

The Joule-Thomson Experiment holds $P$(pressure on the left side) and $P'$(pressure on the right side) constant.

Link for description of the experiment:
http://tccc.iesl.forth.gr/education/local/Labs-PC-II/JT.pdf

Is it possible then to consider the entire process as two constant pressure processes? Personally, I think it is feasible.

Which would yield $H=C_pdT=0$, since $dT$ is none zero? That would require $C_p$ to be zero, which it is not clearly.

This explained the process as proposed (2 constant pressure processes)

[Joule Thomson Coefficient derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/joule-thomson-coefficient-derivation/288157#288157)

Which clearly causes a contradiction as $dH = C_p(dT)$ would give you none zero $dH$ for the overall process.

Explanation is appreciated.

Comment: The JT experiment you are referring to is flow of a gas through a valve or a porous plug, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: OK.  If you are familiar with the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics, what does that tell you about the change in enthalpy for a gas passing through an adiabatic valve or porous plug from the high pressure side to the low pressure side?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why it would be considered an open system. As far as I know the apparatus (pistons+gas) is isolated and adiabatic.

Comment: The system is the valve or porous plug.  Gas flows into and out of each of these systems.  You did say you were looking a such systems, correct?

Comment: I don't think considering the porous plug as the control volume is feasible. Because there is no way of measuring internal energy change with respect to time as well as transfer of heat. Gas on each side of the plug would be considered surroundings in this case and there will be a change of internal energy due to temperature difference of the gas entering and leaving.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.  This is a standard problem that is very often  used to illustrate the application of the open system (control volume) version of the 1st law of thermodynamics for a steady state flow.  Have you learned about the open system version of the first law yet?

Comment: http://imgur.com/F0svPWR
the above version is the one we learned. I see how you can get net change of enthalpy equal to zero with the assumption of steady state, negligible KE,PE, Q, and shaft work.

however, as stated above, I do not feel the assumption of steady state and adiabatic would apply if you choose your system to be the porous plug. in addition, my original question was asking if it's feasible to break the process into two isobaric processes. thank you for the answers so far.

Comment: Well, if nothing is changing with time at a given spatial location while gas flows through the plug, the system is at steady state.  And, if the plug is small (and maybe also insulated), then not much heat is transferred out of the gas as it passes through the plug (which is usually thought to be only a couple of inches long).  So, ideally, the system is adiabatic.  In a way, the process is broken down into two isobaric processes, when considering the work required to push gas into and out of the plug.  This corresponds to the $\Delta (Pv)$ part of the $\Delta H$.